Add information to firebase from textfields to create a post
I am trying to add the information from this page :  to firebase and to make it appear on user profile like this 
But I don't know if I wrote ok the details at the beginning of the code and what I should write to textfields and continue button to retrieve the information correctly to the firebase ... here it's the code that I am using. Any idea what I should add to complete the code? Or it's even the good way I done it?
    class WorkoutContentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WorkoutContentPage({super.key});

  @override
  WorkoutContentPageState createState() => WorkoutContentPageState();
}

class WorkoutContentPageState extends State<WorkoutContentPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map>>? stream;
  String? userId;
  String? nameprogram;
  String? typeprogram;
  String? typeequipment;
  TextEditingController nameprogramController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController typeprogramController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController typeequipmentController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      nameprogram = (value.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["nameprogram"];
      typeprogram = (value.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["typeprogram"];
      typeequipment = (value.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["typeequipment"];
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Workout Content',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Center(
                child: Column(children: [
              Text(
                'Add details about your entire workout program',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: nameprogramController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Name of the program",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  filled: true,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: typeprogramController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Type of program(ex: strength, cardio, yoga",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  filled: true,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: typeequipmentController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Type of equipment used",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  filled: true,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 250,
                height: 70,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => WorkoutContentPage()),
                    );
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "+Add photo/video for cover",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Text(
                  'We suggest you to do a short video of 10-15 sec with some exercise that your program has so the user can get an idea of what to expect'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 250,
                height: 70,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => WorkoutContentPage()),
                    );
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Set price",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 240),
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (nameprogramController.text == "") {
                  _alertNoText(context);
                } else {
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("nameprogram")
                      .doc()
                      .set({
                    'userID': userId,
                    'nameprogram': nameprogramController.text,
                    'typepromgram': typeprogram,
                    'typeequiment': typeequipment
                  });
                   setState(() {
                                        nameprogramController.clear();
                                      });
                }
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Continue',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _alertNoText(BuildContext context) {
    Alert(
      context: context,
      type: AlertType.warning,
      title: "Post",
      desc: "You have not written any text",
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          width: 120,
          child: const Text(
            "Close",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ).show();
  }
}

